# How to join two objects in blender where one of them has an array modifier?

Tags: modifiers, objects

I have an object that has no array modifier with it but other has an array modifier added to it. Now since I select them both using Shift key, I don't find that array modifier working anymore. I know that the object that I select last is the parent object, but is there any way that can affect the array on the original object but doesn't the other?

Comment: You mean joining with `Ctrl`+`J`, not parenting. The joined object will inherit the modifier(s) of the **active** object, which is usually the last one with `Shift`-clicking, but maybe not if you use other selection methods. So the one with the brighter outline then the other selected ones. The problem is when joining them you cannot keep part of it with and the other without modifier (except for modifiers which can be limited to vertex groups), so in order to preserve the visual appearance of both you have to apply the modifier before joining them, which makes the change permanent.

Answer (score 0):

If you parent objects, they retain their modifiers, it doesn't matter if you parent A to B or B to A.

Comment: Clearly the question is about joining, not about parenting as the the issue described suggests and the title correctly says.